# AWS RDS DB Connection Count per User

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

You can you please help me in this matter, My requirement is this how can I get the database connection count per user in a weekly time-period i.e weekly report.

I am using AWS RDS Mysql

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you can parse the query log for that

Comment: what kind of query logs. can you please elaborate here.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-logs.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.html#USER_LogAccess.Procedural.UploadtoCloudWatch you can export the db logs to cloudwatch and process them with for example a lambda filter